# WooCommerce Subscriptions aligning the Payment date to 2 month in the future?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, subscriptions

The Subscriptions plugin allows for the payment date to be synchronised to the first of each month, more specifically to the first of the following month. So if someone registers in January they would be charged on the February 1st. However I need the ability for them to be synchronised/aligned to be charged on 1st of March., is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Woo Support? They should be able to tell you if it is possible.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?